# What kinds of grocery stores tend to carry guava?

Tags: fruit

I cannot find guava in the grocery stores near me. The only grocery store that was selling guava closed last week and since then I have been to Food Lion, Wegmans, Walmart etc. but I cannot find guava.

Does anyone know what type of grocery store carries them?

Comment: Yep, it's gonna get closed. Your question is unanswerable... as we don't even know where you are. If we did, this would be too specific and still get closed. Sorry, region specific forum maybe. Or try an Asian grocery store...

Comment: At best, we can provide a generic answer to where guava can typically be found. That's how I tried to craft my answer below. The only people who can tell you for certain whether they carry guava are your local grocers.

Comment: Simply unanswerable.

Comment: Try stores with a large Latin American inventory.

Comment: The title did make this look pretty bad, but even the original form asked what *type* of stores carried guava - I think that general answers like logophobe's are actually pretty useful, and applicable across pretty much the whole US if not other western countries.

Comment: I agree with @Jefromi. This is a valid question and logophobe's answer captured it pretty well. The OP did not ask for a specific name of a store, simply what type of store may carry them. Perhaps we shouldn't be so quick to jump on the idea of closing and downvoting - at least not without proper consideration.

Comment: Usually good ones do.

Comment: Suggested rephrase: What ethnic and/or social groups eat a lot of guava, and where are the stores these people frequent typically found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really difficult to say for certain which of your local grocers will carry guava; depending on your location, they may be a seasonal item or simply not locally available.  In my experience, guava is fairly common in southeast Asian and Central American cuisines, so you could try an ethnic grocery.  But that just changes the question to whether you've got an Asian or Latin market around.

Guava *juice* is frequently available in co-ops and natural foods stores, and [can be ordered in cartons online](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004741B4Y) (though it's not cheap).  You might also find it in the ethnic aisles in big-box groceries.

Finally, if you're *really* desperate, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guava#Distribution) tells me that:

> They are one of the few tropical fruits that can grow to fruiting size in pots indoors. When grown from seed, guavas can bear fruit as soon as two years, or as long as eight years.

So there's a potential long-term solution to your supply problem... but if you want to know about that, you're best off asking [on another SE site](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can also sometimes find frozen guava puree even when fresh aren't available (I've seen it in Latin stores).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Indian and Mexican grocery stores carry guavas.  In Nothern California, there is a store called Pacifica that almost always carries guavas.